# Test that two function variables point to the same function?

Tags: r

How can I test that two function variables point to the same function?

```
test = lm
test2 = lm

test == lm     # error: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
test == test2  # error: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Comment: Note these two functions dont 'point to' the same function, they are independent _copies_ of the lm function code.

Comment: right...functional programming =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
identical(test, lm)
identical(test, test2)
```